# How did I get my Nexus 7 homescreen into landscape?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, home-screen, nexus-7, orientation

I was playing around on my Nexus 7 today and somehow ended up in a landscape version of the homescreen. I haven't downloaded any apps that mess with it like Ultimate Rotation Control, or rooted it or anything. Somehow though, it was in landscape and I thought it looked pretty cool. As soon as I switched into a different app and came back it was stuck in portrait again though.

Does anybody know how that would have happened? I'd like to at least mess around with it in landscape, especially since it seems to be built in.

EDIT: It looks like if you open mVideoPlayer and lock the screen, then it will open up to the landscaped homescreen when you unlock. However it rotates back. It doesn't look like the orientation being in landscape messes up anything, so why would it be locked in portrait?

EDIT: The above method worked the first three times but doesn't seem to do it at all anymore.

Comment: Since this doesn't answer the question, Custom Launchers like Apex or Nova allow you to use your homescreen in landscape mode. They look like the stock launcher also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More of a status update than an answer: Jelly Bean 4.1.2 allows a landscape rotation on small screens.

I previously had the same experience (accidentally changed the rotation but could not reproduce it) -- I received the system update yesterday and was pleasantly surprised after the reboot  :-)

Comment: Yup, I received a stock update to 4.1.2 the other day which added landscape support for the home and lock screens.